# Can someone explain the difference between these JS functions one with callback and other no with callback

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, callback

To sort an array we can do:

1.

```
var values = [0,3,2,5,7,4,8];
console.log(values.sort());
```

2.

```
var values = [0,3,2,5,7,4,8];
values.sort(function(v1,v2){
    return v1-v2;
});
console.log(values);
```

Both give the same output, but which one is faster or better?

Comment: Try adding some 2-digit numbers to the array, and compare the results.

Answer (score 3):

They're not equivalent unless all the numbers in the array have the same number of digits. The default comparison function for `sort()` compares the array elements as strings, not as numbers, and the string `"10"` is less than `"2"`. You can see the difference if you add a 2-digit number to the array.

```js
var values = [0,3,2,5,7,4,8, 10];
console.log(JSON.stringify(values.sort()));
console.log(JSON.stringify(values.sort(function(v1,v2){
    return v1-v2;
})));
```

Comparing their performance seems pointless, since they do different things, and it's likely that the first form is simply wrong.

Comment: so you mean to say that the first method values.sort(); does not work for the array  var values = [0,3,2,5,7,4,8,99,45]; then when should we use the sort to sort array this is confusing for me.

Comment: @Brenton You can use it for sorting arrays of strings. `["dog", "cat", "elephant"]`.

Comment: i understand, then what do you think is the best way to sort numbers?

Answer (score 1):

So the first `.sort()` call uses the default comparer, which can be found referenced in this documentation.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

"If compareFunction is not supplied, elements are sorted by converting them to strings and comparing strings in Unicode code point order."

The second sort uses your custom comparer, which does an integer comparison instead of string comparison.

The second should be faster since it doesn't need to do the string conversion on top of the comparisons.